# How to set dynamic size for Android's view?

Tags: android, json, android-layout

I am trying to set the minimum sizes, but still one view is taking over completely. My normal view looks like this:
[image]

These two values are coming from the server. But if the size of the "hello" changes to something longer then the number string disappears.

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
if (jsonDataViewType.get(i).toString().equals("editBox")) {
                editText = new EditText(context);
                editText.setMinLines(1);
                editText.setMinimumWidth(10);
                linearLayoutHorizontal.addView(editText);
                editText.setText(jsonDataValue.get(i));
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.weight = 1.0f;
                editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                editText.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
            else if(jsonDataViewType.get(i).toString().equals("button")) {
                helloButton = new Button(context);
//              helloButton.setMinLines(1);
                linearLayoutHorizontal.addView(helloButton);
                helloButton.setText(jsonDataValue.get(i));
                // testing
//              helloButton.setText("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhheeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeelllllllllllllllllllllllllllooooooooooo");
            }
```

I am setting both the minLines and minWidth, but as you can see its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that setting `setMinLines(1)` is a lower bound setting meaning that at minimum make this one line long. If you want to control how much is being shown you need to `setMaxLines(1);` and then the same for width setting `setMinWidth(10)` means at least let this be 10 wide so do `setMaxWidth(10)`

Then you may want to consider adding ellipsize to the buttons text if you want it to show that there is more text but its cut off.

**Update**
If you want them to sit next to each other:

```
// Linear Layout has weight sum of 3
linearLayoutHorizontal.setWeightSum(3.0f);

// Lets EditText take up 2/3 of view
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2.0f);

editText.setLayoutParams(params);


// Button gets the other 1/3
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);

helloButton.setLayoutParams(params2);
```

Comment: But I don't know what the max length could be as this is coming from server. So this is why I wanted to set the minimum not the maximum.

Comment: So your adding these to a LinearLayout then? How do you want them to display? one next to the other?

Comment: Everything is linear.

Comment: Yes, the hello and the number string should be next to eacher.

Comment: I think I liked your ellipsize idea better. What will this updated solution do?

Comment: It sets your LinearLayouts weightSum = 3 and then sets the edittext for 2/3 of that space and button for 1/3 of that space.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `layout_width=0` for both `EditView and`Button`. Then set layout_weight to 0.8 and 0.2
So theese two view will fill parents width. Now your EditView is out of the screen left side.

Comment: hey there's no such thing as editText.setLayout_width... How would I do pragmatically?